# How to unit test method which invokes another method?

Tags: java, oop, unit-testing, junit, mocking

How to test method which invokes another method? In my example I would like to know how to test `initComponentsTypeA` which invokes `create` method.

```
public MyClass{

private List<TypeA> componentsTypeA;

public void initComponents(Config c){   
    componentsTypeA = initComponentsTypeA(c);
    //...
}

private List<TypeA> initComponentsTypeA(Config c){
    //...
    List<MyObject> someList = c.getSomeList();
    List<TypeA> localList = new ArrayList<>();
    for(MyObject mo : someList){
        localList.add(create(mo));
    }
    return localList;
}

private TypeA create(MyObject myObject){
    // ...
}
}
```

I know that one solution is to refactor code in this way (show below). But is it necessary? Is it the only solution?

```
public MyClass{

private List<TypeA> componentsTypeA;

public void initComponents(Config c){   
     List<MyObject> myObjectList = initComponentsTypeA(c);
     componentsTypeA = create(myObjectList)
    //...
}

private List<MyObject> initComponentsTypeA(Config c){
    //...
    List<MyObject> someList = c.getSomeList();
    return someList;
}

private List<TypeA> create(List<MyObject> myObjectList){
    // ...
}
}
```

In the second, refactored example the names of the methods are should be also changed, accordingly to their meaning.

Comment: What's the problem with the first approach and how does the second one solve it?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `mockito` and either create a mock that return real methods, then override the behaviour for the method you want to mock, or use spy, which creates a mock that wraps a real instance of your object.

Here's a tutorial on [mockito spy](http://stevenschwenke.de/spyingWithMockito).

**Edit**:

Since the method to be mocked is private, and as @fge mentioned, you would need mocking library that exposes private method. And [powermock](https://code.google.com/p/powermock/wiki/MockPrivate), does just that.

Comment: However, it won't spy private methods; you'd need PowerMockito for that.

Comment: Creating a mock of the class under test defeats the entire purpose of unit testing. You end up testing a mock instead of the logic of your class.

Comment: I do agree. When you find yourself thinking of mocking the class under test, this means that the design itself should probably be revisited. But sometimes, you can't afford to do that if you're adding functionality to existing code and you have to test your additions anyway. In such cases I would rather test even in a sloppy way that leave the code untested for the sake of purity.

Comment: Mocking the class under test is often worse than no test at all. Lot of resources expended for a totally misleading result.

Comment: @ylabidi I agree that sometimes you need to make tough choices like that. One would need to really consider the long term effects since I generally find that sloppy tests can cost you in the long run...and testing private methods just makes for very brittle tests. It would probably be better to make a method public until the design could be changed even though it pains me to say that...

Answer (score 1):

Given that `initComponentsTypeA` is a private method, you wouldn't unit test it directly. You only ever want to unit test your public methods which then exercise your private members. You can confirm the effect of your private methods by looking at the side effects created by the calls to your private methods.

So in your case, you would test `initComponents`. It is likely that in order to see what is going on within `initComponents`, you would need to pass in a mock Config object so you could verify that it is being used correctly and to control what it returns when `getSomeList` is called. You would be able to confirm the effect of `initComponentsTypeA` and `create` by looking at the effect your call to `initComponents` had to other properties of the `MyClass`.

If you don't have a way to see the changes to `MyClass`, you would need to consider refactoring your class to make that possible. You need to think of your tests as testing `MyClass` from the persective of another class that is going to use `MyClass`. If that class can't see or benefit from the effect of calling `initComponents` then it isn't much use to anyone.

Hopefully that is not too vague of an answer...let me know if you'd like me to clarify anything I've said above.

Comment: It's as vague as my very similar answer. :)

Comment: @TonyHopkinson yeah, it's difficult to write a non-vague answer without taking the time to re-write the test in the question... I just don't have the time to do that at the moment. :-)

Comment: I didn't find it vague. Looks like OP didn't use TDD to achieve the design, or took a 'erm short cut.

Comment: @TonyHopkinson I agree...based on the current design of MyClass, I very much doubt TDD was used to create such a class. It would seem that the OP is trying to retrofit tests onto a poorly designed class.

Answer (score 0):

You need to choose.
Either you delegate all the private stuff to other classes, the methods are now public and your problems go away.

Or you are saying all that private stuff is private and as you don't test implementation. Any test on initComponents would have to be an indirect one.

If it's private from a unit testing point of view you could get rid of, or rename or otherwise twiddle with MyClass's implementation and hopefully have no impact on it's behaviour.

It's a black box, or it's not...